# Lucene/Solr aggregation

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, solr

I faced with large problem. Lucene can not aggregate data. What alternative solution available.

After some improvement I have and need next :

lucene data example

```
product_id   distri_id   stock 
1            d1          10
1            d2          20
1            d3          23
```

I need do query with next condition for example:  prod_id =1 and distri_id = (d1 or d2) and stock(sum of d1 and d1) > 13.

So I must aggregate data per dsitri and select where sum of stock more the some value. In other SQL terminology I must do GROUP BY distri HAVING sum(stock)>13.

Can somebody suggest what to do in this case.

Thanks!

Best regards, 
Artem

Comment: Could you write how many rows of data you have? Could also add which db you tried?

Comment: Postgresql. Indexing data comparable with tens millions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [field collapsing patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-236) which I guess offers similar functionality.

Also, [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/solr-result-grouping-field?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zones%2Fcss+%28CSS+Zone%29) says:

> <..>introduced Solr’s Result Grouping,
>   also called Field Collapsing, that
>   limits the number of documents shown
>   for each “group”, normally defined as
>   the unique values in a field or
>   function query. <..> You’ll need a recent nightly build of
>   Solr 4.0-dev, or the newly released
>   LucidWorks Enterprise v1.6, our
>   commercial version of Solr.